# Создание задержки перед запуском корутины

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть метод, запускающий одновременно 3 корутины. Мне нужно что бы эти корутины запускались не одновременно, а через некоторое время после запуска предыдущей, как это можно реализовать?

```
    StartCoroutine(F1DOWN(rect1));
    StartCoroutine(F2DOWN(rect2));
    StartCoroutine(F3DOWN(rect3));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать "главную корутину", которая будет управлять запуском других корутин:

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(F_Caller(1f, 2f));
}

IEnumerator F_Caller(float delay2, float delay3) {
    StartCoroutine(F1DOWN());
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay2);
    StartCoroutine(F2DOWN());
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay3);
    StartCoroutine(F3DOWN());
}

IEnumerator F1DOWN() {
    Debug.Log("F1DOWN");
    yield return null;
}

IEnumerator F2DOWN() {
    Debug.Log("F2DOWN");
    yield return null;
}

IEnumerator F3DOWN() {
    Debug.Log("F3DOWN");
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: В сишарпе нет calllater?

Comment: @eri что такое calllater? Впервые слышу.

Comment: @eri вы удивлены, что в шарпе нет функции из питоновского фреймворка? Вот так сюрприз :) Корутины конкретно в юнити - это **не** асинхронный код,  это просто механизм, которые позволят вызывать тот или иной код с удобством таймеров или цепных вызовов.

Comment: Этот код запускают следующую корутину только после того как завершилась предыдущая.А мне нужно что бы они работали параллельно,  запущенные в разное время.

Comment: @VladislavSit да, потому что я не знаю код ваших корутин, если они представляют из себя обычные функции без задержек и прочего, то каким образом они будут работать параллельно?

Comment: @VladislavSit и нет, в коде `F_Caller` эти корутины запускаются по истечению времени задержки, а не "после завершения предыдущей".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker действительно, все правильно работает, моя ошибка была. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @VladislavSit всегда пожалуйста ;)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вот и я о том же. Это таймеры, а таймеров как таковых нет...

Comment: @eri я перестал вас понимать, корутины - специфическая часть юнити, я не совсем уверена что вы понимаете, как они в юнити работают, но при этом что-то хотите мне про них сказать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я просто выразил удивление что нет обычных таймеров изкоробки.

Comment: @eri эм, они есть, называется `WaitForSeconds`. Можно запаковать **каждую** корутину в другую корутину, которая будет ждать `n` секунд и вызывать корутину, вот только зачем, если проще сделать так, как я указал в ответе.